# Ubuntu Server 20.04 installer fails on Alienware R10

Tags: server, alienware

I'm back, now with a different error on a different version of the installer. I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS on an Alienware R10 prebuilt with a custom MOBO, 3900X processor, and a RTX 2080ti as the graphics card. The system is set to boot in UEFI, with secure boot disabled, and AHCI controller. I am trying to install this to a completely empty SSD with LVM groups disabled and no custom partition control. After running for a while the installer eventually exits with the following failure messages `FAIL: installing GRUB to target divice`, `FAIL: Configuring target system bootloader` and `FAIL: curtin command curtinhooks`. I'm not sure if it matters but a few lines above this it says `Invalid BootOrder order entry value1003` followed by `efibootmgr: entry 1003 does not exsist` If there is any more information I can provide please let me know.